# Why might I be getting the undefined columns err?

Tags: r, data-visualization

I am using the timeline library on the following dataset:

```
'data.frame':   3951 obs. of  4 variables:
 $ Problem  : chr  "A" "B" "C" "D" ...
 $ Device   : chr  "V" "W" "V" "W" ...
 $ StartDate: Date, format: "2008-01-24" "2008-01-11" ...
 $ EndDate  : Date, format: "2007-11-25" "2007-10-16" ...
```

This is exactly the same data structure as provided by the library's ww2:

```
'data.frame':   8 obs. of  4 variables:
 $ Person   : chr  "Franklin D. Roosevelt" "Harry S. Truman" "Stanley\nBaldwin" "Neville\nChamberlain" ...
 $ Group    : chr  "US President" "US President" "UK Prime Minister" "UK Prime Minister" ...
 $ StartDate: Date, format: "1933-03-04" "1945-04-12" ...
 $ EndDate  : Date, format: "1945-04-12" "1953-01-20" ...
```

After I run

```
timeline(df,group.col=df$Problem,start.col=df$StartDate,end.col=df$EndDate)
```

It returns

```
Error in `[.data.frame`(df, , start.col) : undefined columns selected
```

Even though I try different str, such as df[,1], it returns the same error. What am I misunderstanding?

Comment: It will be useful if you post output of dput(df) here.

Answer (score 1):

Study the documentation and then use:

```
timeline(df, group.col="Problem",
             start.col="StartDate",
             end.col="EndDate")
```

Comment: timeline(df, events, label.col = names(df)[1],
group.col = names(df)[2], start.col = names(df)[3],
end.col = names(df)[4], text.size = 4,
text.color = "black", num.label.steps = 5,
event.label.col, event.col, event.group.col,
event.spots = 1, event.label = "",
event.label.method = 1, event.line = FALSE,
event.text.size = 4, event.above = TRUE, limits, ...)

Comment: the format presented in the last sentence,which was made during the initial post, matches the formatting presented in the documentation thank you.

Comment: there is actually another question which is more accurate to my understanding which is related to the reading of the documentation--- why did you choose "Problem" and neither df[,"Problem"](?unsure about this), df[,1] or df$Problem. They are all legitimate ways of interpreting the documentation.

Comment: According to the documentation the function expects column names for these parameters. The column name is "Problem". Your suggestions are the columns, not their names.